# Combination-Permutation-Probability

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, permutations, combinations

This is a two part question. The first part seemed easy to me (perhaps I didn't get it correct, but it seemed simple). The second part I've worked through many scenarios and can't reconcile.

Question:
Larisa is trying to solve a word puzzle. She needs to arrange the letters H, P, S, T, A, E, and O into a two-word arrangement.

1) How many different arrangements of the letters can she make?

nPr (7,7) = 7! = 5040

2) Assuming that each arrangement has an equal chance of occurring, what is the  probability that she will form the words tap shoe on her first try?

The book gives the answer as 1/30240. I have tried for hours and can't get the same answer. I'm sure I'll feel foolish when I see how to get there .

I see the problem as a couple of key scenarios: **How many ways can 7 letters be divided into 2 groups** and **how many permutations can be made in each group**? No matter what I've tried I can't get to the solution in the book.

Note that this is an Algebra 1 book and the book doesn't cover combination / permutations with repetition. But this question is labeled "critical thinking" and I believe is meant to challenge the reader.

FWIW, I'm an adult considering getting a 3rd degree in a quantitative field and decided before enrolling in anything I would review all mathematics I took previously through Calculus. This is one of the only Algebra 1 problems that gave me trouble and it's making me feel foolish . I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a "blank" letter. At first hand there are $8!=40320$ arrangements, but the blank letter is not allowed to be the first or the last, since it is the interspace between the words. That means that $2\times7!=10080$ must be subtracted.$$8!-2\times7!=40320-10080=30240$$

Comment: Thank you, this is a good way to conceptualize this that I hadn't considered! With the help of this community I feel like I totally get it now (and missed something very obvious in my first attempt).

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your math-refreshment.

Answer (score 2):

In part one, you calculated number of ways to arrange letters into one word. But you are supposed to create two words, so every seven letter word has how many possible splittings into two words?

Comment: And once you have corrected part one, you actually have the answer for part two, since "tap shoe" is just one possible two-words arrangement among all the ones you have counted in part one.

Comment: Thanks so much, it was so simple and in front of me and I didn't even see it. Thanks for your help!!